# dynamic DOM and browser back button

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

In test participated Ff, Safari, Opera, IE and Chrome

FF, Safari and Opera are behaving as expected. When i modify DOM dynamically, leave the page and press back button - the content will remain as it were

Now Chrome is on the same level as IE. Back button will load initial state of previous page. This is bad. In my case, the solution would be to store the state to server session and show it when page is loaded. Therefore.. is there a way to disable page cache in IE and Chrome so page is fetched from the server all the times?

some have suggested to add

```
window.onunload = function () { };
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One of options is to reset modified elements to their initial state on `DOMContentLoaded`/`pageshow` events.

Comment: how do i make difference of back button and refresh then?

Comment: i only need to load the stored state from server when back button is pressed.

Comment: Consider using [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

Comment: history api is available since IE 10. i would need solution for older versions also

Comment: So what you need is probably to prevent browser caching completely via corresponding server HTTP-response headers. I usually use combination of several headers to prevent browser caching: `Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT` (any date in the past), `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0`, and `Pragma: no-cache`.